# Will Apple reject App use HTTP protocol via lower-level networking APIs

Tags: ios, http, app-transport-security

As document says:

> ATS protections are not available when using lower-level networking APIs provided by Apple, or when using third-party networking libraries.

I test this by using Xcode 8, iOS9 device, with C++ socket related APIs, and result shows, http communication (with lower-level networking APIs) works well with default ATS enabled.

Will Apple reject App that use HTTP protocol via lower-level networking APIs, especially after 2017/01/01 ?

Comment: As far as I know, Apple already forces you to use HTTPS __everywhere__ if you don't explictly define exceptions. The only thing that will be changed in January is, that you can't simply submit yor App with an exception defined in the info.plist.

Comment: You can still use http after January, you just need to explain why. For example there are a whole range of embedded devices that will never support TLS with public certificates

Comment: Did you run your tests using a build from Xcode 7 / 8 on a iOS 9 or newer device. If so, you should be fine doing what you are doing without having to provide Apple justification.  ATS exceptions are only needed if iOS is blocking calls that your app is making.  Justification / rejection by Apple is only a concern if you are using ATS exceptions and submitting to the store after 12/31/2016.

Comment: Also, how exactly are you making those http calls?  I'm pretty sure anything using an NSURLConnection is monitored by ATS. Are you doing things at a lower level than that?

Comment: @wottle I'm using C++ socket related APIs, Xcode 8, test on iOS 9 device.

Comment: See my answer below based on your response.

Answer (score 0):

If you are making your own networking calls outside the high level classes Apple provides (NSUrlRequest, UIWebView, WKWebView, AVPlayer, etc.), Apple will not reject you due to ATS.  Apple's request for justification on submit is just if you have enabled ATS exceptions in your Info.plist.  Those will be detected on submit and Apple will require a justification and may reject your app because of it.  If you aren't needing to do any ATS exceptions due to handling the network calls at a lower level, you should be fine.

Of course, Apple could change that in the future (the whole concept behind ATS is to ensure apps are trying to properly secure data in transit).  But for right now, as long as none of the low level API calls you are making are private APIs, you should be good.